# Is there a better/faster way to Fuzzy Match Customer Data in SQL than this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My Customer Table is around 1.3 million rows. The program that tried to match customers was not working as intended and it has resulted in tons of customers not being matched to existing customers.

One of the biggest issues that the program has is that it tried to use Billing Email as its match. The program with this is that we have customers from many different markets, which include markets that encrypt customer emails such as Amazon.com.

So email matching is only an option on specific websites and marketplaces.

I would like to know if there is a better way(than what I have tried below) to do a "4-way match" on my customer table so that I can see if there are many matches against different columns.

for example:

```
ListAEmail                              | ListAFullname | ListAAddress | ListAPhone
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2b************@marketplace.amazon.com   | jeff neal     | 49 willow    | 4*******7
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Would be a Match on 2 of the 4 to this

```
ListBEmail                              | ListBFullname | ListBAddress | ListBPhone
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1********@gmail.com                     | jeff neal     | 7-49 willow  | 4*******1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It would Match 100% on [ListBFullname] and 83.33% on [ListBAddress] so I would consider this a Matched Customer and I would like to assign the same CustomerID to this person for both his orders.

I think my stored procedure below(which I have modified from [this article](http://www.decisivedata.net/blog/cleaning-messy-data-sql-part-2-fuzzy-matching-optimized) ) can be optimized somehow but I am not seeing it. It has been running for over 15 hours. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create procedure [dbo].[FuzzyMatchBigData] (

@MatchScore float = .8

) AS

TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[TempMatch]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TempMatch]

SELECT ListA.BillEmail as ListAEmail
      ,ListA.FirstName+' '+ListA.LastName AS ListAFullname
      ,ListA.Numbers AS ListAAddress
      ,ListA.Phone as ListAPhone
      ,ListB.BillEmail as ListBEmail
      ,ListB.FirstName+' '+ListB.LastName AS ListBFullname
      ,ListB.Numbers AS ListBAddress
      ,ListB.Phone as ListBPhone
,CAST(0 AS float) as Matchscore0
,CAST(0 AS float) as Matchscore1
,CAST(0 AS float) as Matchscore2
,CAST(0 AS float) as Matchscore3

FROM (
SELECT CASE WHEN LOWER(BillEmail) = '' OR LOWER(BillEmail) = 'N/A' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))
            ELSE LOWER(BillEmail)
            END as BillEmail
        ,CASE WHEN LOWER([BillFirstName] + ' ' + [BillLastName]) = '' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))
        ELSE LOWER([BillFirstName] + ' ' + [BillLastName])
        END as BillName
        ,LOWER([BillFirstName]) as FirstName
        ,LOWER([BillLastName]) as LastName
        ,LOWER(BillCity) as BillCity
        ,LOWER(BillCompany) as BillCompany
        ,LOWER(BillCountryCode) as BillCountryCode
        ,CASE WHEN replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(
                                            replace(
                                                replace(
         LOWER(BillPhone),'-',''),')',''),'(',''),' ',''),'*',''),',',''),'+',''),'&',''),'.',''),'=',''),'/','') = '' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))
         ELSE replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(
                                            replace(
                                                replace(
         LOWER(BillPhone),'-',''),')',''),'(',''),' ',''),'*',''),',',''),'+',''),'&',''),'.',''),'=',''),'/','')
         END as Phone
        ,LOWER(BillPostalCode) as BillPostalCode
        ,LOWER(BillStateProvCode) as BillStateProvCode
        ,replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(
                                                replace(
                                                    replace(
         LOWER([BillStreet1] + ' ' + [BillStreet2]),'-',''),')',''),'(',''),'*',''),',',''),'+',''),'&',''),'.',''),'=',''),'/',''),'#','') as 'Address'
        ,CASE WHEN LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(BillNumbers, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')) = '' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))
        ELSE LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(BillNumbers, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')) 
        END as Numbers
FROM (
SELECT [CustomerID]
            ,CASE WHEN BillEmail = '' OR BillEmail = 'N/A' THEN ShipEmail
            ELSE BillEmail
            END as BillEmail
            ,CASE WHEN BillFirstName = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipFirstName], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillFirstName], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillFirstName
            ,CASE WHEN BillLastName = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipLastName], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillLastName], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillLastName
            ,CASE WHEN BillCity = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipCity], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillCity], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillCity
            ,CASE WHEN BillCompany = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipCompany], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillCompany], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') 
            END AS BillCompany
            ,CASE WHEN BillCountryCode = ''THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipCountryCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') 
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillCountryCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') 
            END as BillCountryCode
            ,CASE WHEN BillPhone = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipPhone], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillPhone], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillPhone
            ,CASE WHEN BillPostalCode = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipPostalCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillPostalCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillPostalCode
            ,CASE WHEN BillStateProvCode = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipStateProvCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillStateProvCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillStateProvCode
            ,CASE WHEN BillStreet1 = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipStreet1], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillStreet1], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') 
            END AS BillStreet1
            ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([BillStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [BillStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', BillStreet1) + 1)) = ''
            THEN SUBSTRING([ShipStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [ShipStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', ShipStreet1) + 1))
            ELSE SUBSTRING([BillStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [BillStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', BillStreet1) + 1))
            END as BillNumbers
            ,CASE WHEN BillStreet2 = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipStreet2], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillStreet2], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillStreet2
            ,CASE WHEN BillStreet3 = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipStreet3], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillStreet3], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillStreet3
  FROM [Customer]
) AS Data2
) ListA

JOIN (
SELECT CASE WHEN LOWER(BillEmail) = '' OR LOWER(BillEmail) = 'N/A' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))
            ELSE LOWER(BillEmail)
            END as BillEmail
        ,CASE WHEN LOWER([BillFirstName] + ' ' + [BillLastName]) = '' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))
        ELSE LOWER([BillFirstName] + ' ' + [BillLastName])
        END as BillName
        ,LOWER([BillFirstName]) as FirstName
        ,LOWER([BillLastName]) as LastName
        ,LOWER(BillCity) as BillCity
        ,LOWER(BillCompany) as BillCompany
        ,LOWER(BillCountryCode) as BillCountryCode
        ,CASE WHEN replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(
                                            replace(
                                                replace(
         LOWER(BillPhone),'-',''),')',''),'(',''),' ',''),'*',''),',',''),'+',''),'&',''),'.',''),'=',''),'/','') = '' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))
         ELSE replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(
                                            replace(
                                                replace(
         LOWER(BillPhone),'-',''),')',''),'(',''),' ',''),'*',''),',',''),'+',''),'&',''),'.',''),'=',''),'/','')
         END as Phone
        ,LOWER(BillPostalCode) as BillPostalCode
        ,LOWER(BillStateProvCode) as BillStateProvCode
        ,replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(
                                                replace(
                                                    replace(
         LOWER([BillStreet1] + ' ' + [BillStreet2]),'-',''),')',''),'(',''),'*',''),',',''),'+',''),'&',''),'.',''),'=',''),'/',''),'#','') as 'Address'
        ,CASE WHEN LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(BillNumbers, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')) = '' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))
        ELSE LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(BillNumbers, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')) 
        END as Numbers
FROM (
SELECT [CustomerID]
            ,CASE WHEN BillEmail = '' OR BillEmail = 'N/A' THEN ShipEmail
            ELSE BillEmail
            END as BillEmail
            ,CASE WHEN BillFirstName = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipFirstName], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillFirstName], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillFirstName
            ,CASE WHEN BillLastName = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipLastName], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillLastName], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillLastName
            ,CASE WHEN BillCity = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipCity], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillCity], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillCity
            ,CASE WHEN BillCompany = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipCompany], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillCompany], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') 
            END AS BillCompany
            ,CASE WHEN BillCountryCode = ''THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipCountryCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') 
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillCountryCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') 
            END as BillCountryCode
            ,CASE WHEN BillPhone = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipPhone], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillPhone], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillPhone
            ,CASE WHEN BillPostalCode = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipPostalCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillPostalCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillPostalCode
            ,CASE WHEN BillStateProvCode = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipStateProvCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillStateProvCode], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillStateProvCode
            ,CASE WHEN BillStreet1 = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipStreet1], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillStreet1], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') 
            END AS BillStreet1
            ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([BillStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [BillStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', BillStreet1) + 1)) = ''
            THEN SUBSTRING([ShipStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [ShipStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', ShipStreet1) + 1))
            ELSE SUBSTRING([BillStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [BillStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', BillStreet1) + 1))
            END as BillNumbers
            ,CASE WHEN BillStreet2 = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipStreet2], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillStreet2], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillStreet2
            ,CASE WHEN BillStreet3 = '' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([ShipStreet3], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE([BillStreet3], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
            END AS BillStreet3
  FROM [Customer]
)as Data3
) ListB
ON MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.FirstName+' '+ListA.LastName, ListB.FirstName+' '+ListB.LastName, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
OR MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.BillEmail,ListB.BillEmail, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
OR MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.Numbers,ListB.Numbers, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
OR MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.Phone,ListB.Phone, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore

UPDATE [TempMatch]
SET MatchScore0 = MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListAEmail,ListBEmail, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore)

UPDATE [TempMatch]
SET MatchScore1 = MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListAFullname, ListBFullname, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore)

UPDATE [TempMatch]
SET MatchScore2 = MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListAAddress, ListBAddress, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore)

UPDATE [TempMatch]
SET MatchScore3 = MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListAPhone, ListBPhone, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore)
```

Edit

Per @John Pasquet suggestion I was able to create a new table with his suggestions applied and shortened my Query to this.

```
DECLARE @MatchScore float = .8
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT ListA.CustomerID as ListACustomerID
      ,ListA.BillEmail as ListAEmail
      ,ListA.FirstName+' '+ListA.LastName AS ListAFullname
      ,ListA.Numbers AS ListAAddress
      ,ListA.Phone as ListAPhone
      ,ListB.CustomerID as ListBCustomerID
      ,ListB.BillEmail as ListBEmail
      ,ListB.FirstName+' '+ListB.LastName AS ListBFullname
      ,ListB.Numbers AS ListBAddress
      ,ListB.Phone as ListBPhone
      ,MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.FirstName+' '+ListA.LastName, ListB.FirstName+' '+ListB.LastName, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) as NameScore
      ,MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.BillEmail, ListB.BillEmail, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) as EmailScore
      ,MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.Numbers,ListB.Numbers,3,1.0, @MatchScore) as NumberScore
      ,MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.Phone,ListB.Phone,3,1.0, @MatchScore) as PhoneScore

FROM (
SELECT [CustomerID]
            ,BillEmail
            ,BillFirstName AS FirstName
            ,BillLastName AS LastName
            ,BillPhone AS Phone
            ,BillStreet1
            ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([BillStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [BillStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', BillStreet1) + 1)) = ''
            THEN SUBSTRING([ShipStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [ShipStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', ShipStreet1) + 1))
            ELSE SUBSTRING([BillStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [BillStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', BillStreet1) + 1))
            END as Numbers
  FROM [CustomerFix]
) ListA
JOIN (
SELECT [CustomerID]
            ,BillEmail
            ,BillFirstName AS FirstName
            ,BillLastName AS LastName
            ,BillPhone AS Phone
            ,BillStreet1
            ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([BillStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [BillStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', BillStreet1) + 1)) = ''
            THEN SUBSTRING([ShipStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [ShipStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', ShipStreet1) + 1))
            ELSE SUBSTRING([BillStreet1], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [BillStreet1],CHARINDEX(' ', BillStreet1) + 1))
            END as Numbers
  FROM [CustomerFix]
) ListB
ON MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.FirstName+' '+ListA.LastName, ListB.FirstName+' '+ListB.LastName, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
OR MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.BillEmail,ListB.BillEmail, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
OR MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.Numbers,ListB.Numbers, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
OR MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.Phone,ListB.Phone, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
) as Data5
WHERE (NameScore+EmailScore+NumberScore+PhoneScore) > 1
```

I ran this as a query to test so I am getting results slowly but surely. It is still very CPU intensive because there are 1.3 Million records. I am hoping I can optimize it a little more before creating the rest of the Stored Procedures that will clean and update the Customer Table.

After I get this initial data Cleanse finished I will be making a SP that will scrub new customers as they come in.

EDIT #2

Added additional Columns and re-indexed the tables so that I could cut down on CPU usage by not comparing concatenated strings. I see at least a 10x speed increase just by adding the 2 additional columns and re-indexing.

```
DECLARE @MatchScore float = .8

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT ListA.CustomerID as ListACustomerID
      ,ListA.BillEmail as ListAEmail
      ,ListA.[Name] AS ListAFullname
      ,ListA.Numbers AS ListAAddress
      ,ListA.Phone as ListAPhone
      ,ListB.CustomerID as ListBCustomerID
      ,ListB.BillEmail as ListBEmail
      ,ListB.[Name] AS ListBFullname
      ,ListB.Numbers AS ListBAddress
      ,ListB.Phone as ListBPhone
      ,MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.[Name], ListB.[Name], 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) as NameScore
      ,MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.BillEmail, ListB.BillEmail, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) as EmailScore
      ,MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.Numbers,ListB.Numbers,3,1.0, @MatchScore) as NumberScore
      ,MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.Phone,ListB.Phone,3,1.0, @MatchScore) as PhoneScore
FROM (
SELECT [CustomerID]
            ,BillEmail
            ,BillFullName as [Name]
            ,BillPhone AS Phone
            ,BillNumbers as Numbers
  FROM [CustomerFix]
) ListA
JOIN (
SELECT [CustomerID]
            ,BillEmail
            ,BillFullName as [Name]
            ,BillPhone AS Phone
            ,BillNumbers as Numbers
  FROM [CustomerFix]
) ListB
ON MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.[Name], ListB.[Name], 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
OR MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.BillEmail,ListB.BillEmail, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
OR MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.Numbers,ListB.Numbers, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
OR MDS1.mdq.Similarity(ListA.Phone,ListB.Phone, 3, 1.0, @MatchScore) >= @MatchScore
) as Data5
WHERE (NameScore+EmailScore+NumberScore+PhoneScore) > 1
```

Comment: That is a tremendous amount of CPU.  When you compare after all of that, you lose all the power of the indexes.  A better way would be to create extra columns with all the REPLACE and LOWER statements.  Then create indexes on those and then run the query.  

You could also run the SELECT with TOP 10 or something like that.  I would profile it to see how inefficient it is, but I doubt you could do much to optimize it.

Comment: This data looks masked, not encrypted. Is that the case?

Comment: @JohnPasquet I am going create the extra columns as you have suggested. I will post my results. Thank you

Comment: @scsimon The data that is marked with ********* is just me protecting the customers. That data is actually stored as nvarchar's

Comment: @NathanHead Yeah... Hope that works out.  Will be interested to hear what happens.

Comment: Be careful matching on `ListA.FirstName+' '+ListA.LastName` without giving extra weight for differing suffixes.

Comment: @JohnPasquet Following up on your suggestion. I have created a new table with the fixes applied. and I was able to shorten the Query to the edit Above

Comment: @SqlZim do you have any suggestions on how I might go about matching the names better? I would love to hear your input.

Comment: @NathanHead It's really difficult to offer much advice without knowing more about what your data looks like and what data is available. I've scrubbed and matched many data sets in the past, and encountered all sorts of quirks. Suffixes just stuck out in my mind because you could encounter same first name, last name, address and match them, but if you had suffix you might easily see that one was junior and the other senior. I've also seen many instances of swapped first & last names, and middle names that get packed with the first parts of the last name in last names that have spaces. etc.

Comment: Yeah, the CPU gets hammered when it compares concatenated strings.  Could you add additional columns for FirstName + ' ' + LastName and then index them?  You could create this as a computed column.  That would help a good bit.

Comment: @JohnPasquet & @ SqlZim I scrubbed the tables last night for records that were not complete. This took the record count down to 1.1 Million and I took the advice for creating an additional column with the concatenated names and added them to the index. I also went ahead and created a new column that for the one that was aliased as 'Numbers'.

Running my initial Query to test, I already see an increase of at least 10-15x the speed. We are heading in the right direction. I will keep you informed today on my progress. Thanks guys.

Comment: Remember to index the new columns as well.

Comment: @JohnPasquet Updating you. I moved this SP to a new server because it was taking ALOT of system resources on our really nice machine which also host the production. I'm stuck with a single Xeon x3470 CPU and 16GB of RAM. Its been running for 6 Days...